Beat Frequency Test for ADC
I'm trying to do beat frequency testing to test the dynamic parameters of the ADC. I am doing what is written in TI's Application Note Dynamic Tests For A/D Converter Performance.
I add a frequency to the sampling frequency to scan each code and give it from the signal generator. Then I sample with the ADC. But when I finally get the FFT of this, I will understand which parameters are suitable for the output I get.

The beat frequency and envelope tests are qualitative tests that provide a quick, simple visual demonstration of ADC dynamic failures. An input frequency is selected that pro- vides worst-case range changes and maximal input slew rates that the ADC is expected to see in use.

(page 2, first paragraph)
I couldn't understand what the dynamic parameters mentioned in the document were. How does slew rate relate and how does the result of this test relate to here?

re 1): literally explained in the text: you look for where your result doesn't look like samples of a perfect sine. missing codes look like jumps, and oversized codes repeated values.

re 2) This is what you need to come clear with before tackling Q1 and Q3. Since three broad questions are too many for a single post anyways, I'm taking the liberty of removing all except Q2 from your question. The original text remains in the history. After understanding the answer to Q2, you should ask a new question, with one of these two removed questions, rephrased based on your (new) understanding :)


I couldn't understand what the dynamic parameters mentioned in the document were

In the text they only mention code failures, with which they mean missing codes and oversized codes.
An ADC converts analog voltages to digital values ("codes"). So, a perfect ADC, excited with voltages all over its analog input range, will produce all valid values. Real ADCs might not be able to do that – a few codes can't be produces, and analog values might get "rounded" to neighbors (or completely broken, other numbers. Know a product where that happened. Not fun.).
These digital values that can't be produced are missing codes. If these get rounded to neighbors, these neighbor values will get produced more often "than they should", which is what TI calls "oversized codes".

How does slew rate relate and how does the result of this test relate to here?

The text mentions that you pick a frequency such that its maximum slew rate is close to the maximum slew rate you would want to use the ADC with. That's easy: Slew rate is simply the voltage difference between consecutive samples, divided by the time difference between samples:
$$r = \frac{\left\lvert s(t_0) - s(t_0 + T)\right\rvert}{T}$$
The good old mean value theorem (from your first math lectures, probably!) says that for a continuous function like the sine, the slope of a line going through two points on a function curve must appear as derivative of the function somewhere between these points. So, what's the maximum derivative of a sine signal $s(t) = A\cdot\sin(2\pi ft),\quad A,f >0$?
$\newcommand{\dt}{\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm{d}t}}$
$$\
\begin{align}
    r_{\max} & \overset{!}{=}\max \left\lvert \dt{} s(t) \right\rvert \\
             & =
    \max A\left\lvert \dt \sin(2\pi ft) \right\rvert       \\
             & =
    A \max \left \lvert 2\pi f  \cos(2\pi ft) \right\rvert  \\
             & =
    2\pi f A \max \left \lvert \cos(2\pi ft) \right\rvert  \\
             & =
    2\pi f A \cdot 1                                       \\
             & = 2\pi f A                                  \\
             & \implies                                    \\
    f
             & = \frac{r_{\max}}{2\pi A},
\end{align}
$$
and since $A$ must be chosen as half the ADC input range for the sine to cover all values, we can simply take the maximum expected slew rate and divide it by $\pi$ times that range to get the frequency of the sine we should use ideally. For our beat frequency to be low, we pick the nearest multiple of the sampling rate plus beat frequency.
Regarding the test approach as a whole
This seems to be a pretty obsolete idea, looking at this from today.
The document says it's from 2011, but I think it's much older, for three reasons:

they use measurement equipment by HP. HP has not produced measurement equipment since 1999, when that was spun off into Agilent Technologies (in fact, the electronics measurement devices department has become Keysight 2013. And, the HP 3325A synthesizer they're using is from 1978. So, it's not unlikely that this methodology is from the late 1970s / early 1980s)
in 2011, "monitors" wasn't synonymous with "CRT" anymore, so that also points to the approach being older, and, most relevant to the result here:
When you're testing an ADC, there's literally no point in making a complicated measurement setup involving specific frequencies higher than the sampling rate, i.e., explicitly inviting behaviour the ADC was not built for, just to look at a monitor to spot discontinuities in a sine wave and then try to figure out where the problem is. What you can display on a screen necessarily also fits into the memory of a computer, oscilloscope or signal analyzer. You'd then write a few lines of python, matlab or the programming language of your choice to verify you saw all codes and the sine wave was free of distortion.

So, I'd simply not do the beat frequency measurement. Record a sufficiently slow sine wave to excite all codes, record a period or multiple to your measurement system's RAM, download to a PC (if that measurement system isn't already the PC), and do offline analysis on that. Less work, equally quick results, but definitive ones.
This method is from a time long past, and while it's worthwhile understanding the way it works, the TI application note falls short of explaining the problems with it, and how to address them.

Great explanation, thank you.
